# Bash bad variable substitution

Tags: bash, shell

I have an install script that was modified about one month agao, it has worked almost everytime except for the 'occssional' failure. Upon investigating the issue i tried running the script manually (bash -x) and found a bad variable substitution error at the following line

```
local HTTPD=${$APACHE_ADDRESS}
```

I changed this to

```
local HTTPD=${APACHE_ADDRESS}
```

..and the script runs manually everytime and install succeeds. The ${APACHE_ADDRESS} variable is sourced from a properties file.  My question is how could this substitution work 95% of the time!?

```
OS= RHEL 6.6
```

Adding context....it is executed as part of flowing scenario

```
batch_config ()
{
does_file_exist ${BATCH_CONFIG}
        # need to get the Datastore 'type'
        local DATASTORE_NAME="OpenDJ"
        local AUTHSERVICE_NAME="ldapService"
        local HTTPDFQDN=${APACHE_SERVER}
        local idmgrName="identity-mgr-service"

        ${CAT} << EOF > ${SSO_BATCH_CONFIG}
create-realm -e ${REALM_NAME}
create-policies -e / -X ${REFERRAL_TEMP_FILE}
create-policies -e /${REALM_NAME} -X ${POLICY_TEMP_FILE}
create-agent -e /${REALM_NAME} -b ${AGENT_NAME} -t WebAgent -s ${BACKEND_SERVER_URL}/${DEPLOYMENT_NAME} -g ${AGENT_SERVER_URL} -a "userpassword=` ${CAT} ${AGENT_ACCESS_FILE} `"
update-agent -e /${REALM_NAME} -b ${AGENT_NAME} -D ${AGENT_ATTRIBUTES_FILE}
create-agent -e / -b idmgr -t J2EEAgent -a userpassword=xxxxxxx -g http://${HTTPDFQDN}:8085/agentapp -s http://myalias.${HTTPDFQDN}:4448/mywar
----
----
```

Comment: What does your VCS history say?

Comment: Probably its inside a conditional block and the conditional will be false in 95% of time?

Comment: that's the confusing thing, the script will be guaranteed to fail if this is not resolved as the HTTPD address is used to configure a back end server. I added context above...if this backend server is not configured then install has failed and no one can log in...

Comment: The only thing I can surely say without checking all the solution: "no magic did happen".. :)

Comment: I suspect the 90% of the time it worked you were actually reading the script name as `local HTTPD`. Meaning, APACHE_ADDRESS  was initialized but not set (defaulting to 0) thus $APACHE_ADDRESS => 0 causing HTTPD=${$APACHE_ADDRESS} to take the value of the first positional parameter.. Stranger things have happened...

Comment: thanks for reply, that appears to be what used to happen in faulted scenario, this script(called from a 'master' script)  would incorrectly exit 0, leaving the install appearing to have succeeded  and logs looking clean but on investigation the backend configuration never suceeded...and on manual running of this file with '-x' the bad substitution error became apparent. the back end configuration would be impossible and guaranteed to fail unless this substitution worked meaning it had to work some  of the time..thanks again for all the replies..and i don;t believe in magic either :)